# Convert non-convex optimization problems into convex optimization problems

Tags: convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Let A ∈ Rm×n, b ∈ Rm, c ∈ Rn, and d ∈ R. Prove that the nonconvex optimization problem
min
x∈Rn
∥Ax−b∥/(c⊤x +d)
subject to ∥x∥ ≤ 1;cTx+d > 0
is equivalent to the convex optimization problem
min (y∈Rn , t)
∥Ay −bt∥
subject to ∥y∥ ≤ t;
c⊤y +dt = 1

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.